# Change SceneKit Node Texture Programmatically SWIFT

Tags: swift, 3d, nodes, textures, scenekit

I have an orc .SCN file. In the orc there is a node of the orc where I assign all the textures. It works when it loads the default loaded skin. When I try to change the skin in code, below, the whole thing just turns greyish white.

Both of the below items create the white orc. Also, it calls twice, for some reason. Why is that?

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
            if node.name == "Orc" {
                let material = SCNMaterial()
                material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "OrcDiffuse2.tga")
                node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = material
      }
}


    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
                if node.name == "Orc" {
                    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "OrcDiffuse2.tga")
          }
    }
```

If I replace the diffuse with the same skin it already has, I get the same result of a soft white mesh:

```
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
                        if node.name == "Orc" {
                   node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "T_Orc_diffuse.png")
                  }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign an entire `SCNMaterial()` to the contents of the diffuse part of your material. You could ether use/configure a `SCNMaterialProperty()` and assign it to `diffuse` or just try the following:

```
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/OrcDiffuse2.tga")
```

If you want to work with an entire `SCNMaterial()` then you have to configure it entirely and assign it like so:

```
node.geometry?.firstMaterial = material
```

Comment: See my edits above. it didn't work for me.

Comment: What happens? Is the result still the same, that greyish/white colour? You could add kind of print statement eacht time you fetch a node, to make sure you fetched the right node. Did you try to filter the node's instead of enumerate them? - Depending on how you add the "Orc" to your scene it is possible that the real geometry you can see is a childNode of the "orc" Node - and the orc node is just the parent node with no geometry.

Comment: The entire figure turns whiteish, almost like ghost, as though the skin was replaced with a single color instead of a file. The node structure does not have any other "Orc" names either. Also, it's the correct node since it's the node I manually add the texture to in X-code. IE, I know it's the correct node.

Comment: you are referencing your UIImage in a wrong manner. Therefor it is never found. Do it like so: UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/OrcDiffuse2.tga") and you should be good. (I also updated my answer above)